# Notepad++ remove comma from string

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have about 5000+ lines in a csv file. Part of each line looks like this:

```
...Name 1:, Smith, John, Name 1 #:...

...Name 1:, Doe, Jane, Name 1 #:...
```

I need a regex that will remove the comma between last and first name so it looks like this:

```
...Name 1:, Smith John, Name 1 #:...

...Name 1:, Doe Jane, Name 1 #:...
```

I have tried every example I could find on Google and Superuser.com

I have gotten as far as being able to select the name with the comma in it with:

```
(?<=Name 1:,).*?(?=, Name 1 #)
```

I am assuming I will need to limit everything down to the characters between "Name 1:," and "Name 1 #:" then select the comma and replace the string excluding the comma.

However this is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like

Find: `Name 1:,(.+),(.+), Name 1 #`

Replace: `Name1:,\1\2, Name1 #`

The parentheses capture the last name and the first name. The `\1` and `\2` in the replacement string refer back to those captures.